# Android: Stretch & Crop Image (but remains Aspact-ratio)

Tags: android, image, crop, stretch

[image]

I would like to stretch and crop an image so that it shows full screen on a Android device.

For example, inside the red-rectangle above would be the only area displayed on the phone.

I want it to center and crop. If the height of the image is small than the height of the device, I want to stretch the image as well.

By the way, I don't NEED images to be cropped. I just want my ImageView to display only the reg-rectangle part given the landscape image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` on your `ImageView` in XML? If I understand what you're asking for correctly, it should do just that.

Comment: Hehe yeah, ScaleType is quite powerful, but often overlooked :-)